# Does Java 9 contain built-in JSON?

Tags: java, json, java-9

I was wondering if Java 9 has built-in support for JSON. If so how can I import it? I'm writing a socket program so I'm not talking about Java EE and my target to import to is a simple Java SE class.

Answer (score 12):

There was a [proposal](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk9-dev/2014-December/001670.html) to drop the feature by Mark Reinhold, Oracle’s Head of the Java:

> We may reconsider this [JSON API] JEP for JDK 10 or a later release, especially if new language features such as value types and generics over primitive types (JEP 218) enable a more compact and expressive API.

And it doesn't appear in the [finalized features](https://dzone.com/articles/jdk-9-is-feature-complete). So it appears Java 9 doesn't have a native JSON API.

Answer (score 7):

There is [JSON-P](https://javaee.github.io/jsonp/) which has a [JSR](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=374).

> JSON Processing (JSON-P) is a Java API to process (for e.g. parse, generate, transform and query) JSON messages. It produces and consumes JSON text in a streaming fashion (similar to StAX API for XML) and allows to build a Java object model for JSON text using API classes (similar to DOM API for XML).

That's as close as you can get to official JSON support in Java.